# Why is document.getElementById considered an object in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I noticed that `document.getElementById` is a function in Firefox and Chrome, while `typeof` considers it an object in IE8 (at least).

Anyone has an idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IE8 (attempts to) implement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#JScript)  [ECMAScript 3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) where the `typeof` operator result is implementation defined for host objects regardless if the object implements [[call]]. In ES5, callable host objects must return `"function"`.

See the table in ECMAScript 3

[image]

Compare to ECMAScript 5.1 http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3

Comment: +1 for actually getting to the root of things. Basically, IE8 is implementing the standard that was in place when it was released; newer browsers are implementing a newer version of the standard, and the standard has changed in the meanwhile.

Comment: So basically, correct if I'm wrong, according to EC3, any object that is not native, undefined, null, Boolean, a Number or a String has no 'official' type? So I could have an implementation of `typeof` where `{}` is a function and `function(){}` is an object, and still be fully compliant (with EC3)?

Comment: @Stilltorik no because both are native.. Host objects are objects provided by the Javascript host. Like a browser provides document.getElementById and so on but it would be impossible to have that in the language itself since language should  not be tied to browser.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks for the explanation!