# If we polyfill fn.bind() in JavaScript, why do you have to check the type of "this"?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I see in the [Mozilla polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) of `fn.bind()` like this:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {

  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {

    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    // other code omitted here...

  };
}
```

I don't understand why we have to check the type of `this`... because if we say `fn.bind()` and `fn` is a function, then it will work, and if `fn` is not a function, then `fn.bind` will never reach `Function.prototype.bind` by prototypal inheritance.  So why do we have to check the type of `this`?

Answer (score 8):

> if `fn` is not a function, then `fn.bind` will never reach `Function.prototype.bind` by prototypal inheritance.

True, however this is not the only way `this` could be set. For example, if we were to use the `.call` or `.apply` methods on the `bind` function itself, or do something really crazy like assign it to other objects, it would behave differently from the native function.

Considering the following code using the native ES5 method:

```js
var notAFunction = {};
var someObject = {};

Function.prototype.bind.call(notAFunction, someObject);
```

This will throw a `TypeError`, like the following:

> TypeError: Function.prototype.bind called on incompatible Object

This extra check is basically emulating this sanity check from the native function as closely as it can.

> So why do we have to check the type of `this`?

You don't technically *have to*, as this case would be an edge-case for most sane code, but in order to make the polyfill behave more-closely to the ES5 spec, it is nice. Since ES5 browsers will never even run this code, there is also no performance hit for modern browser.

This behavior [is defined in the ECMA-262 5.1 Edition specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) and onward:

> 1. Let *Target* be the **this** value.
> 2. If IsCallable(*Target*) is **false**, throw a **TypeError** exception.

Answer (score 3):

Not all callable objects inherit from (or are equal to) `Function.prototype`. For example:

```
typeof document.createElement('object') === "function"; // true
document.createElement('object') instanceof Function; // false
```

And even objects which inherit from `Function.prototype` could have `bind` shadowed:

```
var f = function() {};
f.bind = 123;
f.bind === Function.prototype.bind; // false
```

However, you may want to be able to call `Function.prototype.bind` on those callable objects. That's why we have things like `Function.prototype.call`, `Function.prototype.apply` or `Reflect.apply`. You can use those to call `bind` on any object, whether it's callable or not.

The inverse is also possible. You can have an object which inherits from `Function.prototype` and is not callable. For example:

```
Object.create(Function.prototype) instanceof Function; // true
typeof Object.create(Function.prototype) === "function"; // false
```

Therefore, you can't make any assumption. If you want the polyfill to conform to ES5, you must check whether the object is callable. In ES5, checking whether `typeof` returns `"function"` does exactly that (but in ES3 it might not work for host objects).

Comment: If someone really still needs to polyfill `Function.prototype.bind` it's because of older JS engines that do not fully comply with ES5, and then the test `typeof X === "function"` must not necessarily mean callable. For example, in IE8, `typeof alert` is `"object"`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975210

Comment: @GOTO0 True, host objects are a pain in the neck, specially on IE.